# What is the meaning of "*" in this compound notation?

Tags: notation

I am reading a book on hydrogen energy (handbook of hydrogen energy), and came across the following compound on the Cu-Cl thermochemical cycle: $$\ce{CuO\text{*}CuCl_2(s)}$$

What exactly is the role of the "*" symbol here, how can I better understand this compound?

Comment: How is this a duplicate of the linked question? They are about different (admittedly equivalent) notations, and the linked answer and none of the replies to it mention use of a "*" at all.

Comment: Although the asterisk is this context denote adduct, it can also mean other things. It can denote [electronically excited states](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What-is-the-specific-definition-of-N2-with-a-superscript-asterisk-and-its-difference-with-some-excited-metastable-species-eg-N2A3-N2a). In organic chemistry, it can denote chiral centers: https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/University_of_Missouri/MU%3A__1330H_(Keller)/25%3A_Chemistry_of_Life%3A_Organic_and_Biological_Chemistry/25.07%3A_Chirality_in_Organic_Chemistry

Comment: A similar post for my above point: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/443235/nuclear-reaction-what-is-the-asterisk-an-indication-of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

${CuO*CuCl_2}$ is  another way of writing $\ce{CuO*CuCl2}$. This substance is a stoichiometric mixture of $\ce{CuO}$ and $\ce{CuCl2}$. The symbol asterisk (*) is often used in chemistry instead of the point or dot (·) , especially when using machine languages like LaTeX.

Comment: I'd argue that using correct typography is one of the strengths of latex. I've never seen anyone deliberately using an asterisk instead of a center dot.